# jQuery DOM element value decrease mysteriously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not even sure how to explain the issue I am facing because this is quite strange.

I have a button click event like the following code

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnAddCart', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(":checkbox[name='app_chk']", '#apps_container').is(":checked"))
    {
        $('#alert').html("");
        console.log(localGet('cart'));
        var arr = [];
        var items = [];
        var subtotal = $('#apps_subtotal').text().trim();
        var total = $('#apps_total').text().trim();
        var cart = localGet('cart');
        var flag = 0;
        var app_id, index, price, name, i_parent, i_parent_name;
        $(":checkbox[name='app_chk']:checked").each(function() {

            index = $('[name=app_chk]').index(this);
            price = $('[name=app_price]:eq('+index+')').val();
            name = $('[name=app_name]:eq('+index+')').val();
            i_parent = $('[name=i_parent]:eq('+index+')').val();
            i_parent_name = $('[name=i_parent_name]:eq('+index+')').val();
           // app_id = $('[name=app_id]:eq('+index+')').val();
            app_id = $('[name=app_id]:eq('+index+')').val();
            console.log('index: ' + index);
            console.log('id: ' + app_id);
            console.log('i_parent: ' + i_parent);

            var position = checkedInLocalStorage('cart', app_id);

            if(cart !== null){//the item with the same id exists
                console.log("pos: "+position);
                if(position > -1){
                    //perform update
                    cart[0].items[position].id = app_id;
                    cart[0].items[position].price = price;
                    cart[0].items[position].name = name;
                    cart[0].items[position].i_parent = i_parent;
                    cart[0].items[position].i_parent_name = i_parent_name;
                }else{
                    cart[0].items.push({
                        id : app_id,
                        i_parent : i_parent,
                        price : price,
                        name : name,
                        i_parent_name : i_parent_name
                    });
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }else{
                items.push({
                    id : app_id,
                    i_parent : i_parent,
                    price : price,
                    name : name,
                    i_parent_name : i_parent_name
                })
            }

        });

        if(cart === null) {
            arr.push({
                items: items,
                subtotal: subtotal,
                total: total
            });
            console.log(arr);
            localStore('cart', arr);
        }else{
            cart[0].subtotal = subtotal;
            cart[0].total = total;
            localStore('cart', cart);
            console.log(cart);
        }

        displayCart();
        $('#cart_wrapper').addClass('visible');
        localStorage.removeItem('apps');
    }
    else
    {
        showError('Please select at least one app to add to cart');
    }

});
```

I do not know why the value of `app_id` for the same object decreases by one every time the button `btnAddCart` is clicked meanwhile the value of the other elements are fine and do not change. There is no operation that changes the `app_id` value in the code.

I also attached the testing log to show that the value of `app_id` of the same index changes mysteriously.

Does anyone know what causes the problem?

[image: testing log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the variable app_id is a reserved variable. Everything works well after I changed the dom's name and variable name to `app_idx`